How to remap the second Windows key to the menu key on Wayland?
My keyboard has dual Windows keys (⊞)  — on Linux the said key traditionally functions as Super. The second (i.e. the right) key has no effect out-of-the-box on my system and I'm accustomed to the more common menu key (the alternative combination being Shift + F10), as a hotkey-preferring user.
Gnome 47.1 detects the key being pressed in:

settings → keyboard → input sources → add input source → [select any] → "the eye" icon (  )

I've also experimented on:

settings → keyboard → keyboard shortcuts → view and customize shortcuts → custom shortcuts → + [create new]

The key is detected as Super, but Gnome doesn't allow mapping a single modifier key (and I don't know the command for the menu key on Gnome):

How can I configure the right Windows key to act as a menu key and bring up a context menu (e.g. the menu that appears when right clicking in a web browser)?

I favor remapping natively over running third-party software which tracks all keypresses.
Please don't give X11-only answers, I use Wayland exclusively.

Consider trying this answer using evtest to identify the key, and updating the hwdb database.
